# Wordpress Ajax returns full html page from functions.php, not echo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using a wordpress ajax call to return simple content from a function in wordpress theme functions.php. However, a full html page is returned instead.

Here is the ajax call

```
<?php   
$ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce("iwhq_beginner_select_course");
?>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery("#beg_golf_course").change(function() {  //do this when course changes

//in Wordpress ajaxurl always points to admin-ajax.php
var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
var course_id = 4; 

//Do the ajax
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        url: ajaxurl,

        //NOTE - the action parameter calls the function in functions.php
        data: { action: 'select_course_aj', course_id: course_id, _ajax_nonce: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>' },


        //display alert on success
        success: function(html){ 
            alert(html);
        } 
    }); //close jQuery.ajax(
    return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

And this is the function in functions.php

```
function select_course_func(){
echo $_POST["course_id"];
die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_select_course_aj','select_course_func');
```

The HTML of the page containing the jquery ajax call is actually displayed in the alert instead of the echo.

Any geniuses out there able to tell me why?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: I did include the nonce call in select_course_func PHP call in functions.php, but got the same result.

check_ajax_referer( 'iwhq_beginner_select_course', '_ajax_nonce' );

Comment: Have you looked at the request/response in Firebug?

Comment: so what exactly is alerting?  youre expecting '4' correct?  whats happening is the div your using the html function on loading and html 404 page?  check the url youre sending the ajax call to.  like Jay Blanchard said you can easily do this in firebug or the network tab in chrome.

Comment: Heres the result when I check the network tab in Chrome: http://www.irishwebhq.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/chrome_network.jpg

I cant understand why it would give me a 302 for admin.php - I tested this link in my code and it linked to http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: Yes John B,  I was expecting 4 to alert but the full HTML page where the ajax call originates is displayed in the alert instead.

Comment: OK the 302 has given me a whole lotta more info.
The user performing this action is a logged in subscriber without access to the admin area. I've previously written code in functions.php to re-direct non-admins to a frontend page, so this user has no access to any files in wp-admin, thus causing the 302.

Is there another way of executing an ajax command in wordpress without using wp-admin/wp-ajax.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, Problem solved. See my last 3 comments above plus...

**!defined('DOING_AJAX')** is a constant that can be used to test that the user is not performing an ajax request. I combined this with my logic for redirecting non-admins to the frontend and it works now.

```
/* check the role of current loged in user for redirection */
add_action('admin_init','rt_checkRole');
function rt_checkRole() {

    global $wp_roles;
    $currentrole ='';
    foreach ( $wp_roles->role_names as $role => $name ) {
        if ( current_user_can( $role ) ){
                    $currentrole = $role;
                }
        }
        if(!defined('DOING_AJAX') && (!$currentrole || ($currentrole != 'administrator' && $currentrole != 'editor'))){
            wp_redirect (site_url().'/front-end-login/');
        }
}
```

Found out about !defined('DOING_AJAX') at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26100/redirect-out-of-wp-admin-without-losing-admin-ajax-php

Thanks to all who commented.

Comment: But why was all of the HTML being returned originally?

Comment: Which file do i add this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do ajax call for non admin user you should use the code below, that will disallow wp-admin access for non admin user but allow ajax call for every user, logged in or logged out user

```
function my_admin_init(){
    if( !defined('DOING_AJAX') && !current_user_can('administrator') ){
        wp_redirect( home_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action('admin_init','my_admin_init');
```