# Creating a new div onclick wordpress+ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a link in worpress page

```
<a onclick="show_trend()" >Trend</a>
```

and i am calling an `ajax` function `onclick`.

```
function show_trend() {

    // This does the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'render_admin_charts_page',

        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

what i want to do when calling this function is  display a div section .for that ,this  is my function

```
function render_admin_charts_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="em-bookings-events">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e('Event Booking Report','dbem'); ?></h2>        
            <?php em_bookings_events_table(); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'render_admin_charts_page' );
```

ajax function is calling but not rendering to `div`

Comment: What is the ``ajaxurl`` here?

Comment: url: "../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",

Answer (score 2):

In `Wordpress` all `Ajax` request will be handled by `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. so you have to make sure the relative path of this url is correct.

Then in the callback function, you have to add `die();`

```
function render_admin_charts_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="em-bookings-events">
            <h2><?php esc_html_e('Event Booking Report','dbem'); ?></h2>        
            <?php em_bookings_events_table(); ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
     die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'render_admin_charts_page' );
```

And the good approach is adding the action to the hook like this,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_render_admin_charts_page', 'render_admin_charts_page' );
```

Comment: ok.now i can call. but i am not able to render the div and in console i am getting all the html content from that page

Comment: And I can't see any rendering events in ajax success callback.

Comment: render_admin_charts_page()  this is the rendering function

Comment: but in ajax you are just logging it to the console.

Comment: See posts like this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10217633/wordpress-ajax-returns-full-html-page-from-functions-php-not-echo